# Bash pgrep regexp function

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I want to create a bash script which would check if the foo is already running and to run it if it's not.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function run {
 if ! pgrep $1;
 then
  $@
 fi
}
run foo
```

After executing the script it starts another instance of foo despite foo is already running.

pgrep foo returns process number so i can make the script kill it first and then start foo again but i want to know if this can be done as described on top.
What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few improvements:

```
function run {
    if ! pgrep -x "$1" >/dev/null
    then
        "$@"
    fi
}
run foo bar "baz qux"
```

notes:

1. quote **all** your variables. That will maintain any words containing whitespace.
2. redirect the output from pgrep
3. use the `-x` pgrep option to restrict the search for processes *named* "foo", as opposed to processes *containing* "foo"

You can shorten this to

```
run() { ! pgrep -x "$1" >/dev/null && "$@"; }
```

We could write `pgrep -x "$1" >/dev/null || "$@"` but that will return a successful exit status if the process is already running, and I think it makes more sense to return a failure status if the process cannot be launched.

Comment: Thank you very much for comprehensive answer.